# How do you document restler api endpoints which are implemented in a base class?

Tags: php, restler

Let's say I have a base class and several derived classes.  Base class implements a method that I want exposed on all derived classes, but I want to the swagger docs to reflect each class properly.  What is the proper way to do this?  Or do I have to override the methods to provide unique documentation for the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the documentation to be unique just override the methods and call `parent::{methodName}();` inside and document the overriding method